# Is there a pun in the name of Ori species / dimensions in the Myth Adventures series?

Tags: humor, myth-adventures

[As Wikipedia notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythAdventures#Known_dimensions) most of the known dimensions and their puns, but doesn't say that the Ori species / dimension's pun, if it exists.

> Ori: A dimension whose inhabitants resemble house cats.

Is there a pun in the novels?

Comment: @DavidW - Well, the pun is said in one page on the internet, "https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1844328941" - Gordian Knot-based. - Since I found it, I'm deleting that bit.